# Importing data frame from R to SQL server using sqlSave() but column truncated to 255 bytes?

Tags: sql, r, import

I have a data frame with multiple columns exceeding 255 characters, when I try to import the data frame to sql server using the code below, multiple columns get truncated to 255 characters.

```
myconn <- odbcDriverConnect("db_name")
sqlSave(myconn, my_data, tablename = "Table_1" ,rownames=FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

**Things I tried but didn't work:**

I tried to create the table in sql before importing the data from R but that didn't work:

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST_Table 
(
      [Column_1] nvarchar(max),
      [Column_2] nvarchar(max),
      [Column_3] nvarchar(max)
);
```

I also tried to specify `varTypes` as below before importing the data:

```
columnTypes <- list(Column_1 = "nvarchar(max)", Column_2 = "nvarchar(max)", Column_3 = "nvarchar(max)")
sqlSave(myconn, my_data, tablename = "Table_1" ,rownames=FALSE, append = TRUE, varTypes=columnTypes)
```

What else can be done to write this data frame to the database as a table without truncating the character strings?

Comment: The only success I've had pushing data from R to SQL was by constructing huge `INSERT` statements with enough sql strings.

Comment: @lebelinoz- can you provide the syntax or an example for the INSERT statements? That's new to me and worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'll give it as an answer below, but I'm not sure if it's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is

```
library (RODBCext)
channel <- odbcConnect (...)

sqlExecute (channel,
          "INSERT INTO Table_1
           (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3)
           VALUES (?,?,?)",
           data = df [c ("Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_3")])
```

Answer (score 0):

The only success I've had pushing data from R to SQL was by constructing huge `INSERT` statements with huge sql strings.  So, assuming I had `Table_1` already on my database and I want to insert a simple dataframe `df` like

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
--------------------------------
Fred      Wilma     Pebbles
Barney    Betty     Bambam
```

Then I'd construct a `sql` string in R like

```
sql = "INSERT Table_1 (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3)
       VALUES ('Fred', 'Wilma', 'Pebbles'), ('Barney', 'Betty', 'Bambam')"
```

and run that on an RODBC connection.